One project (Django 3 with mod_wsgi installed within py 3.8 venv) works but another (Django 5 with mod_wsgi installed within py 3.12) fails
Issue: Internal Server Error with Django and mod_wsgi on Ubuntu Server
Setup:

Ubuntu 20.04
Python 3.8 for existing project (and the base python for the OS too)
Python 3.12.4 for new project
Apache
mod_wsgi installed in respective virtual environments. The system level one has been removed.

Projects:

Existing Project (Working ✅)

Directory: /var/www/existing-project/
Python Version: 3.8
Django Version: 3.x
Virtual Environment Path: /var/www/existing-project/venv
WSGI File Path: /var/www/existing-project/project/project/wsgi.py
Apache Configuration:
Protocols h2 http/1.1
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
LoadModule wsgi_module "/var/www/existing-project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so"

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName existing-project.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/existing-project/project/
    RemoteIPHeader CF-Connecting-IP

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/existing-project_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/existing-project_access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/existing-project/project/project>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    Alias /favicon.ico /var/www/existing-project/project/static/images/favicon/favicon.ico
    Alias /static /var/www/existing-project/project/static

    <Directory /var/www/existing-project/project/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
        <FilesMatch "\.(png|jp?g|gif|ico|mp4|wmv|mov|mpeg|css|map|woff?|eot|svg|ttf|js|json|pdf|csv)">
            ExpiresActive on
            ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
        </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>

    WSGIDaemonProcess existing-project python-home=/var/www/existing-project/venv python-path=/var/www/existing-project/project
    WSGIProcessGroup existing-project
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/existing-project/project/project/wsgi.py

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =existing-project.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>




New Project (Not working ❌)

Directory: /var/www/new-project/
Python Version: 3.12.4
Django Version: 5
Virtual Environment Path: /var/www/new-project/venv
WSGI File Path: /var/www/new-project/project/project/wsgi.py
Apache Configuration:
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
LoadModule wsgi_module "/var/www/new-project/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py312.cpython-312-x86_64-linux-gnu.so"

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName new-project.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/new-project/project/
    RemoteIPHeader CF-Connecting-IP

    # Basic HTTP Authentication
    <Directory /var/www/new-project/project>
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Restricted Area"
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
        Require valid-user
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/new-project_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/new-project_access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/new-project/project/project>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    Alias /favicon.ico /var/www/new-project/project/static/images/favicon/favicon.ico
    Alias /static /var/www/new-project/project/static

    <Directory /var/www/new-project/project/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
        <FilesMatch "\.(png|jp?g|gif|ico|mp4|wmv|mov|mpeg|css|map|woff?|eot|svg|ttf|js|json|pdf|csv)">
            ExpiresActive on
            ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
        </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>

    WSGIDaemonProcess new-project python-home=/var/www/new-project/venv python-path=/var/www/new-project/project
    WSGIProcessGroup new-project
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/new-project/project/project/wsgi.py

    # RewriteEngine on
    # RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =new-project.com
    # RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>





Issue:
When accessing new-project.com, I receive an "Internal Server Error" with the following error logs:
[wsgi:error] [pid 1198771] mod_wsgi (pid=1198771): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/new-project/project/project/wsgi.py'.
[wsgi:error] [pid 1198771] Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/www/new-project/project/project/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Confirmed Django installation:
(venv) $ pip show django
(venv) $ python -m django --version
         5.0.6


Verified permissions:
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/new-project/
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/new-project/


Checked mod_wsgi path and installation:
(venv) /usr/bin$ mod_wsgi-express module-config
LoadModule wsgi_module "/var/www/new-project/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py312.cpython-312-x86_64-linux-gnu.so"
WSGIPythonHome "/var/www/new-project/venv"
ldd /var/www/new-project/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py312.cpython-312-x86_64-linux-gnu.so


Verified Python version in WSGI script:
import sys
import os
print("Python executable:", sys.executable)
print("Python version:", sys.version)
print("Python path:", sys.path)
print("Current working directory:", os.getcwd())

[wsgi:error] [pid 1201444] Python executable: /var/www/new-project/venv/bin/python
[wsgi:error] [pid 1201444] Python version: 3.8.10 (default, Mar 25 2024, 10:42:49)
[wsgi:error] [pid 1201444] [GCC 9.4.0]
[wsgi:error] [pid 1201444] Python path: ['/var/www/new-project/project', '/usr/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.8', '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload']
[wsgi:error] [pid 1201444] Current working directory: /



Question:
I've been stuck on this for three days and I am out of options to troubleshoot. How can I resolve the "ModuleNotFoundError"? What is happening here?

make sure you are pointing to right venv as listed python executable  is 3.8 and not 3.12

This is what I have in the .conf file WSGIDaemonProcess new-project python-home=/var/www/new-project/venv python-path=/var/www/new-project/project. Do I need to have any additional settings?
